# Is there any way to resolve placeholder in beanName?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wqh">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:custom.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <bean class="com.wqh.demo.TestBean" name="${custom.beanName}" />
</beans>
```

When I use configuration like this, Spring will create BeanDefinition with beanName `${custom.beanName}`, and will not resolve the placeholder inside it.
But I want to use the beanName which declared in `custom.properties` file, is there any way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: you can't assign variable as bean name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration would result in `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` when attempting to get the bean from context.

```
<bean class="com.wqh.demo.TestBean" name="${custom.beanName}" />
```

However , the XML Template Proposals for attribute name shows the following

> Attribute : name Can be used to create one or more aliases illegal in
> an (XML) id. Multiple aliases can be separated by any number of
> spaces, commas, or semi-colons (or indeed any mixture of the three).
>
> Data Type : string

Based on this , the following work around is possible

Considering the properties file entry is :

```
custom.beanName=propBeanName
```

Provide the bean configuration with multiple alias names as follows

```
<bean class="com.wqh.demo.TestBean" name="testBeanName ${custom.beanName}"  />
```

Now when you `getBean()` based on the name from the application context , it would retrieve the bean successfully

Sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-context.xml");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ctx.getAliases("testBeanName")));
    TestBean bean = (TestBean)ctx.getBean("propBeanName");
    System.out.println(bean);
}
```

would display the following in the console

```
[propBeanName]
com.wqh.demo.TestBean@4c60d6e9
```